# SQLite очень медленно происходит вставка в таблицу

Tags: golang, go-sqlite

Почему вставка в таблицу происходит очень медленно. Для примера я решил вставить 1000 записей, что по времени вылилось ~1 минуту? Это вообще как? Что я делаю не так?
Вот пример:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type record struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
    field3 string
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./data.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    OpenCreateTable(db)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        if err := Insert(db, record{"One", "Two", "Three"}); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func OpenCreateTable(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, field1 TEXT, field2 TEXT, field3 TEXT);`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Insert(db *sql.DB, r record) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO records (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(r.field1, r.field2, r.field3); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Конфиг компа:
Процессор   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 МГц, ядер: 6, логических процессоров: 12
16Gb DDR3
ST1000DM010-2EP102

Comment: на первый взгляд, достаточно одного раза  prepare

Comment: еще перед вставками можно начать транзакцию и завершить по окончании. проверьте, может у вас коммитится каждая запись.

Comment: @nexoma    
вынес в цикл, чуть быстрее на ~10 сек
db.Begin()
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
 if _, err := stmt.ExecContext(ctx, r.field1, r.field2, r.field3); err != nil {
  tx.Rollback()
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
}
if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
 log.Fatal(err)
}

Comment: Антон, вот неправильно вы ведёте диалог, надо также написать какой эффект вы получили. но вам уже написали практически готовое решение. у меня остаётся нереализованным предложение что prepare должно быть выполнено только один раз перед всатвками.

Comment: дополнение :) уж извините. делайте "Править" ваш вопрос, так будет правильнее. можете добавить "upd." что бы читателям был понятен прогресс решения вопроса. все таки текст программ трудно читать в одну строку.

Comment: @nexoma спасибо за помощь, замечания учту.

Comment: если есть время, попробуйте всё-таки один prepare перед всеми вставками!

Comment: @nexoma Уже попробовал, без видимым изменений.

Comment: ок. спасибо. ужидал большего. значит это поможет на миллиардах :)

Comment: @Антон насчёт предварительной подготовки - улучшение практически на 50%, вместо 30 25-30мс получилось 15 мс на транзакцию.

Comment: @PakUula Вы правы. Просто предварительную подготовку я выносил ещё до того как обернуть последовательность вставок в транзакцию.

Comment: @Антон если у вас только один читатель-писатель, вы можете отключить синхронный доступ к файлу `sql.Open("sqlite3", "./data.db?_sync=0")`.  это грандиозно ускоряет процесс даже без транзакции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оберните вашу последовательность вставок в транзакцию

```go
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type record struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
    field3 string
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./data.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    start := time.Now()
    OpenCreateTable(db)
    if err := Begin(db); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        if err := Insert(db, record{"One", "Two", "Three"}); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    Commit(db)
    dt := time.Now().Sub(start)
    fmt.Println("Duration: ", dt)
}

func OpenCreateTable(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, field1 TEXT, field2 TEXT, field3 TEXT);`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Insert(db *sql.DB, r record) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO records (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(r.field1, r.field2, r.field3); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Begin(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`BEGIN`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Commit(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`COMMIT`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

У меня получилось 25-30 миллисекунд.

**UPDATE**

Если вынести `Prepare` для `INSERT` во внешний код, то ускорение практически в два раза.

```go
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type record struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
    field3 string
}

var (
    insertStmt *sql.Stmt
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./data.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    start := time.Now()
    OpenCreateTable(db)
    if err := Begin(db); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    insertStmt, err = db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO records (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        if err := Insert(db, record{"One", "Two", "Three"}); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    Commit(db)
    dt := time.Now().Sub(start)
    fmt.Println("Duration: ", dt)
}

func OpenCreateTable(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, field1 TEXT, field2 TEXT, field3 TEXT);`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Insert(db *sql.DB, r record) error {
    var err error
    if _, err = insertStmt.Exec(r.field1, r.field2, r.field3); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Begin(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`BEGIN`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Commit(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`COMMIT`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Получается стабильно 15 миллисекунд

Ещё кучу миллисекунд можно добыть, если отключить синхронный доступ. Для этого нужно указать ключ `_sync=0` в строке где открывается файл:

```
sql.Open("sqlite3", "./data.db?_sync=0")
```

Можно до кучи добавить `&_journal=OFF`, но там выигрыш получается не столь значительный.

Comment: а допустимо ли вывести prepare, он же нужен только раз?

Comment: Благодарю. Вы мне очень помогли. Так стало действительно быстро. Раньше только с маленькими данными работал и не замечал скорости.

Comment: @nexoma Одноразовый Prepare дал значительный прирост. Также очень помогла прагма `SYNCHRONOUS`

Comment: воооооот, огромное спасибо :)  Pak Uula